# How does a HTTP redirect work in the Play Framework?

Tags: playframework, http-redirect

I know what a `3xx` response does in principle but I am unable to understand some aspects of the behaviour.

There is a URL (http://localhost:9000/ws/users/signup/2c23d802-8722-4e62-8b21-f021bc66ac77). On clicking the URL, a request goes to my web application. On receiving the request, the application replies with `303` using `Redirect("www.google.com")` of Play Framework.

I thought that the client will now send a new request with URL `www.google.com` but instead it sends `http://localhost:9000/ws/users/signup/www.google.com`. Why? Does redirect happen within the context of a web server or could I redirect it to a different server?

Comment: Try `Redirect("https://www.google.com")`. When you just have `www.google.com` it's being interpreted as a relative path to your web application which is why it gets appended to the end of the URL. By specifying the protocol ("https://") it should force your web server software to redirect to the correct URL.

Comment: thanks. Happy to accept your answer